функция bot.register_next_step_handler() из TelagramBotAPI
Вроде чуть-чуть знаю библиотеку TelegramBotAPI, решил изучить aiogram, и сразу столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как сразу захватывать ответ пользователя после того как он ответил на вопрос бота. Так вот, в telebot за это отвечает функция
bot.register_next_step_handler()
А в aiogram есть функция с таким же действием? Нигде просто не смог найти.

Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию. приглашаем вас пройти тур => ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Не совсем понял зачем это..

чтоб понять как работает сайт, как тут работает база данных вопросов/ответов. Сформируйте ваш вопрос так, чтоб он был полезен и для других в дальнейшем, то есть если коротко то очевидно, что ответ на ваш вопрос -нет, в aiogram нет прямого аналога функции register_next_step_handler() тем более вы и сами искали. В aiogram подход более структурированный, и там по-моему FSM, но код полностью тут врят ли кто напишет, без учета ваших попыток. Поэтому напишите, что пробовали, что не получилось. Ознакомьтесь со справкой, как  задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Я и сам недавно столкнулся с этим, после перехода на Aiogram3.
Обычно здесь не пишут готовые решения, если не предложены попытки, но я сам сталкивался с недопониманием, поэтому вот.
Здесь совершенно другой подход к решению таких задач. Вместе указания следующей функции, здесь используется FSM (машина состояний), в которой отслеживается текущее состояние, можно динамически их переключать и перенаправлять.
Для сравнения, я Вам дам два идентичных по функционалу кода, но на двух библиотеках для наглядности:
Telebot:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def test(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Пожалуйста, введите своё имя')

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, new_func)

def new_func(message): 
    name = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'{name} — какое красивое имя. Рад с Вами познакомится.')

Aiogram3:
import aiogram

from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State

class Form(StatesGroup):
    name = State() 

@dp.message(Command('start'))
async def test(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Пожалуйста, введите своё имя")
    await state.set_state(Form.name)

@dp.message(Form.name)
async def new_func(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    name = message.text
    await message.answer(f"{name} — какое красивое имя. Рад с Вами познакомиться.")
    await state.clear()

Таким образом, Вы можете заранее объявить все нужны состояния, а затем указывать на какой переключится и затем очистить состояния, чтобы выйти из этого.
Полезные ссылки:
Неплохая статья
Есть вот такое видео-объяснение
Официальная документая
